# How to apply conic gradient to svg stroke?

Tags: css, svg, stroke

Is any idea how it can be done?

Expecting this:[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-apply-conic-gradient-to-svg-stroke-cbx37l

Comment: It seems like it possible with pattern with image inside of it

Comment: I do not know how to move pattern to left, now it in the middle, and it need to be responsive. I'm given up

Comment: The codesandbox example doesn't seam to have anything to do with the stroke issue except the naming of the URL. Could you add your own attempt to solve this to your question?

Comment: @chrwahl you are right, i missed last letter in the link. Here is working url: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-apply-conic-gradient-to-svg-stroke-cbx37l

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement it with pattern image.
https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-apply-conic-gradient-to-svg-stroke-cbx37l

Comment: please don't use services like codesanbox, please read [answer]

Comment: answer have codesandbox link but must be on snippet

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here is that four rectangles that have there own linear gradient are masked off by a dotted stroke. The gradients overlap overlap each other in the corners so it looks like a continues gradient.

The dotted stroke in mask m1 has rounded line caps and then another mask (m2) is masking off half of the stroke.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 300"
  width="500">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="top">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="DarkViolet"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="DeepSkyBlue"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="right" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="DeepSkyBlue"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="Green"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="Yellow"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="bottom">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="Red"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="Orange"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="Yellow"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="left" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="10%" stop-color="DarkViolet"/>
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="Red"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect x="4" y="4" rx="20" width="392" height="292"
        mask="url(#m2)" stroke="white" stroke-width="8"
        stroke-dasharray="5 5 10 5 7 4" stroke-linecap="round"
        pathLength="400" filter="url(#distort)" />
    </mask>
    <mask id="m2">
      <rect x="4" y="4" rx="20" width="392" height="292" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#m1)">
    <rect width="400" height="20" fill="url(#top)"/>
    <rect width="20" height="300" x="380" fill="url(#right)"/>
    <rect width="400" height="20" y="280" fill="url(#bottom)"/>
    <rect width="20" height="300" fill="url(#left)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time, i appreciate it. I prefer simple solutions. If I don't find an easier solution, I'll try your way ♥